# Why does $E[X]$ not equal the integral of $f(x)^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If $X$ is a random variable with the pdf $f(x)$ and $Y=g(X)$ how come $E[Y]$ is the integral of $g(x)f(x)$ but $E[X]$ is the intergral of $xf(x)$ ??

Comment: Because it makes sense? If $g$ is the identitical mapping, i.e. $g(x) = x$, then $Y=X$ and $\mathbb{E}g(X) = \int g(x)f_X(x) = \int xf_X(x) = \mathbb{E} X$.

Comment: Right, the E(f(x)) = integral of f(x)^2

Comment: @Joseph Check wether my edit is okay. I left out the word 'independent' because it is not relevant in this question. There can only be independence in relation to others rv's.

Comment: Yes this is fine :)

Comment: why would it???

Comment: Do we consider the random variable X to = x

Comment: @Joseph : Conventionally (capital) $X$ represents a random variable and (lower-case) $x$ represents the variable with respect to which one integrates in $\int f(x)\,dx$.  This makes it possible to understand an expression like $\Pr(X\le x)$, in which both $X$ and $x$ occur. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition, for every positive function $g$ you have
$$
Eg(X) = \int f(x)g(x) dx.
$$
and if $E|g(X)|<\infty$ you have the same definition as well.

So if $g(x)=x$, as soon as $E|X|<\infty$ you have
$$EX= \int x f(x) dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb E(X)$ is the integral of $xf(x)\,dx$ **because** $\mathbb E(g(X))$ is the integral of $g(x)f(x)\,dx$.